# Batch insert into database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have a list of writer names in a txt file and I want to insert them into my database with single query, but don't know how to do.

My .txt file is very well structured, one writer name occupies a single line.

```
Writer A
Writer B
Writer C
Writer D
```

My form (I can only insert one value with that)

HTML (index.php) (I removed mysqli_real_escape, db connection, etc. to make my question short)

```
<form id="add-book-form" action="insert.php" method="post">
label for="book-name">Book Original Name: </label>
<input type="text" name="book_original_name" id="book_name"/>
```

PHP (insert.php)

```
$stmt = $sqli->prepare("INSERT INTO book(book_original_name) VALUES (?)");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST['book_original_name'];
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

How can I achieve it? Even if you provide me a hint, I will look into it.

I am using phpMyAdmin and using InnoDB, so I can insert records by hand but since there are thousands of them, I need to find a shortcut.

Comment: [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html)

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html

Comment: Thanks, I should have looked into the doc first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can.
You should have styled your file using cvc,xls editors and define columns and `tabs` in your file. then use this [tutorial](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/loading-tables.html)